# Creating new CUDA project with parallel nsight 2.2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, nvidia, nsight

I just update my Nsight from 2.1 to 2.2 and after that i've always got this when new CUDA 4.x project creates:
User canceled out of save dialog (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004000C (OLE_E_PROMPTSAVECANCELLED))
I've got this in VS 10 with CUDA 4.2
Configuration - win7 x64 + GTX 560 + GeForce 210

Comment: Try removing both Nsight and VS. Then reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking for the date of this answer, I've tried hard to make CUDA 4.x with Nsight Visual Studio. But the problem was persistent and reinstalling things didn't help me. After a huge disappointment of this failure, I decide to give CUDA 5 a try.

It installs from a single installer; includes SDK,Toolkit, examples,Nsight Visual Studio, GPU driver and works like a charm. But it only contains 5.0 runtime for development.

NOTE: running Windows 8

Comment: Are you seeing the same error dialog as the original poster with your CUDA 4.x project?

Comment: @JeffDavis yes. do you think I should note it more explicitly?

Comment: Do you mind emailing me at devtools at nvidia dot com? I haven't been able to reproduce the issue and may need more information.

Comment: @JeffDavis I couldn't mail you(actually failed) since the mail delivery is rejected by nvidia domain.I've tried using 2 different mail accounts. Please provide me another e-mail address.

Comment: Whoops. I gave you the wrong email. Its supposed to be devtools-support at nvidia dot com. Sorry about that! I did find your email listed on your github though. I have sent you an email regarding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just encountered the same problem with CUDA 4.2 and Visual Studio 2010. It's solved though after I switch to CUDA 5.0.